# Remove item from objects array

Tags: reactjs

I have a page that renders contatcs informatios:

```
contactsInfo.map((info, index) => (
                <SearchResultPanel
                  info={info}
                  isAdmin={isAdmin}
                  key={index}
                  handleChange={this.makeHandleChange('searchResultPanel')}
                />
              )),
```

The `contactsInfo` is an array of `contactInfo` objects.

On the `SearchResultPanel` component I have an option to delete the current contact:

```
<button onClick={() => this.handleDelete(info.id)}>
```

and the `handleDelete` function:

```
handleDelete = async contactID => {
    await deleteContact(contactID);
    this.setState(contactInfo:
        this.state.contactInfo.id === contactID? {} : this.state.contactInfo,
    }));
  };
```

If I delete the contacts in a descending order for ex `contacts[2]`, `contacts[1]`, `contacts[0]` everything works fine, if I delete the contacts in an ascending order for ex `contacts[0]`, `contacts[1]`, `contacts[2]`, the first `contact` gets deleted but in a `console.log` I see that **the state of the second contact is also being cleared** however the second contact still shows on the page, then when I hit its delete button nothing happens...

What am I doing wrong ont the `handleDelete` method that causes such a behavior?

`componentDidUpdate` function: To update the parent component's state:

```
  componentDidUpdate(_, prevState) {
    const { handleChange } = this.props;
    if (this.state !== prevState) {
      handleChange(prevState.contactInfo.id);
    }
  }
```

and the parent `handleChange` function:

```
  makeHandleChange = panelName => contactID => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      contactsInfo: prevState.contactsInfo.filter(i => i.id !== contactID ),
    }));
  };
```

Entire parent component:

```
import React from 'react';

import SearchResultPanel from '../home/SearchResultPanel';

const contactInformation = [
  {
    id: 123,
    routingNumber: 2634545,
    name: 'test',
    date: '01/23/2019',
  },
  {
    id: 1234,
    routingNumber: 2634546,
    name: 'test2',
    date: '01/23/2012',
  {
    id: 1235,
    routingNumber: 2634547,
    name: 'test3',
    date: '01/23/2012',
 },
];


const getContacts = async () => {
  …
};



export default class Home extends React.Component {
  state = {
    contactsInfo: [],
    isAdmin: true,
  };

  handleSubmit = async () => {
    const contactsInfo = await getContacts();
    this.setState({contactsInfo });
  };

  makeHandleChange = panelName => contactID => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      contactsInfo: prevState. contactsInfo.filter(i => i.id !== contactID),
    }));
  };

  render() {
    const { contactsInfo, isAdmin } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <TextInput
            handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          />

          {{
              contactsInfo.map((info, index) => (
                <SearchResultPanel
                  info={info}
                  isAdmin={isAdmin}
                  key={index}
                  handleChange={this.makeHandleChange('searchResultPanel')}
                />
              )),
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Entire child component:

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import InfoItem from '../ui/InfoItem;


const deleteContact = async contactID => {
};

export default class SearchResultPanel extends Component {
  state = {
    contactInfo: {},
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { info, handleChange } = this.props;
    this.setState({contactInfo: info });
    handleChange(this.state);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(_, prevState) {
    const { handleChange } = this.props;
    if (this.state !== prevState) {
      handleChange(prevState.contactInfo.id);
    }
  }

  handleDelete = async contactID => {
    await deleteContact(contactID);
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      contactInfo:
        prevState.contactInfo.id === contactID? {} : prevState.contactInfo,
    }));
  };


  render() {
    const { info, isAdmin } = this.props;
    const {
      routingNumber,
      name,
      date,
    } = info;

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <InfoItem header="ROUTING NUMBER" detail={routingNumber} />
              <InfoItem header="NAME" detail={name} />
         <InfoItem header="DATE" detail={date} />
            </div>
          </div>
                <button
                  onClick={() => this.handleDelete(info.id)}
                >
                  <DeleteIcon />
                </button>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle with your code?

Comment: you should not use index of array as a key if you have stable id from contact ``info.id``

Comment: @user3378165, show us all the code of parent & child component. Looks like you make mistake to manage state.

Comment: @MahediSabuj Thank you, please see my edited question.

Comment: @fard Thank you! That was what caused the unexpected behavior, I fixed the `key` and that solved the issue! Would you want to write it an as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are
>   removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give
>   the elements a stable identity.

In your code you are using index of array as a key, which is not recommended.

> We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may
>   change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues
>   with component state. 
>   React will default to using indexes as keys.

You should use your `info.id` from `contact`, because then you declare stable identity

```
contactsInfo.map(info => (
                <SearchResultPanel
                  info={info}
                  isAdmin={isAdmin}
                  key={info.id}
                  handleChange={this.makeHandleChange('searchResultPanel')}
                />
              )),
```

source: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the `handleDelete` function. I think you are just missing the open curly brace of `setState` function.

```
handleDelete = async contactID => {
  await deleteContact(contactID);
  this.setState({
    contactInfo: this.state.contactInfo.id === contactID? {} : this.state.contactInfo,
  });
};
```